# How to represent an array of objectID of mongoose in Graphql Schema

Tags: node.js, graphql, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to convert a rest backend with node and mongoose to use GraphQL but i dont know how to represent something like an array of objectID of mongoose schema in graphql schema. My doubt, how do i make this think be a list of Chapter ObjectIds? Didn't find anything alike

mongoose schema

```
const mongoose = require('../database/db')

const BookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: {
       type: String,
       require: true,
   },
    author: {
       type: String
    },
    sinopsis: {
        type: String
    },
    chapters:[{ 
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Chapter'
    }],

}, {
    timestamps: true,  
})

const ChapterSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    number: {
        type:Number
    },

    content: {
        type: String
    },

}, {
    timestamps: true,
})

const Chapter = mongoose.model('Chapter', ChapterSchema)

const Book = mongoose.model('Book', BookSchema)

module.exports.Book = Book
module.exports.Chapter = Chapter
```

GraphQL Schema:

```
type Book {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    author: String
    sinopsis: String
    chapters: [ID] (here is my doubt, how do i make this think be a list of Chapter ObjectIds)

}
type Chapter {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    number: String!
    content: String!
}

type Query{
    books: [Book!]!
    book(id: ID!): Book
    bookChapters(id: ID!): [ID]

    chapter(id: ID!): Chapter!

}

type Mutation {
    createBook(name: String!, author: String!,
     sinopsis: String!, chapters: [ID!]): Book

    createChapter(name: String!, number:String!,
     content:String!): Chapter
}
```

This is the error that i got.

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Field \"chapters\" must not have a selection since type \"[ID]\" has no subfields.",
        "locations": [
          {
            "line": 3,
            "column": 14
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

BookResolver.js

```
const db = require('../models/Book')


module.exports = {

    Query:{
        books: () => db.Book.find(),    
        book: (_,{id}) => db.Book.findById(id),
        bookChapters: (_,{id}) => {

            const book = db.Book.findById(id)
            /* console.log(book + "aaa") */
            const chapterlist = db.Chapter.find(book)
            return chapterlist

        },
        chapter: (_,{id}) => db.Chapter.findById(id),
    },

    Mutation:{
        createBook: (_, {name, author, sinopsis}) => db.Book.create({name, author, sinopsis}),
        createChapter: (_, {name, number, content  }) => {   
            db.Chapter.create({name, number, content})
        },
    },

}
```

Comment: Your GraphQL schema is fine. As you have it, it will return an array of IDs, which will be serialized as strings. The error you are seeing has to do with how you are querying your schema, not with the schema itself. If a field returns a scalar or a List of scalars, it won't have additional child fields (i.e. you can't request additional fields under `chapters` because there are no fields)

Comment: Oh thanks for the reply, i'll run some tests tody to see if i can make this query work i got what you said so i'll try to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer that fits my problem, this is the final archives

BookResolver:

```
const db = require('../models/Book')
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
const prepare = (o) => {
    o._id = o._id.toString()
    return o
  }

module.exports = {

    Query:{
        books: () => db.Book.find(),    
        book: async (_,{id}) => await db.Book.findById(id),
        bookChapters: async (_,args) =>  {
            const book = await db.Book.findById(args.id)

            const chapterList = await db.Chapter.find( {_id: book.chapters})

            return chapterList 


        },
        chapter:  (_,{id}) =>  db.Chapter.findById(id),



    },

    Mutation:{
        createBook: (_, {name, author, sinopsis}) => db.Book.create({name, author, sinopsis}),

        createChapter: async (_, args) => {   
            const chapt = await db.Chapter.create(args)

            const book = await db.Book.findById(ObjectId(chapt.bookId))

            let chapterList = book.chapters
            chapterList.push(chapt._id)

            const result = await db.Book.updateOne({
                "_id": chapt.bookId
            },{
                "$set": {
                    "chapters": chapterList
                }
            })
            return prepare(await db.Chapter.findById(chapt.id))
        },
    },

}
```

schema.graphql:

```
type Book {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    author: String
    sinopsis: String
    chapters: [ID]

}
type Chapter {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    bookId: ID!
    number: String!
    content: String!
}

type Query{
    books: [Book]
    book(id: ID!): Book
    bookChapters(id: ID!): [Chapter]

    chapter(id: ID!): Chapter

}

type Mutation {
    createBook(name: String!, author: String!,
     sinopsis: String!, chapters: [ID!]): Book

    createChapter(name: String!, bookId: String!, number:String!,
     content:String!): Chapter
}
```